# Migrating from IoCContainer to IServiceProvider

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm migrating my API to ASP.NET Core. In my old project I have service registration like this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   ...

   var container = IoCContainer.Instance;

   container.RegisterType<IEventStoreUnitOfWork<IDomainEvent>, EventStoreUnitOfWork<IDomainEvent>>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
   container.RegisterInstance(typeof (IUnitOfWork), container.Resolve<IEventStoreUnitOfWork<IDomainEvent>>());

   ...
}
```

I can't figure out how to reproduce a second line (registration of IUnitOfWork) with `IServiceProvider` in ASP.NET Core project. What I don't understand is how to make something like `container.Resolve<IEventStoreUnitOfWork<IDomainEvent>>`.

Comment: One solution will be to make a class inherit from `IEventStoreUnitOfWork<IDomainEvent>` e.g `MyDomain : IEventStoreUnitOfWork<IDomainEvent>` and then use Resolve on it.

Comment: @OrelEraki - I'm working with legacy project which I don't quite understand yet but what do you mean is make yet another class that will inherit IEventStoreUnitOfWork<IDomainEvent>? How would I use it then?

Comment: Is second line supposed to be singleton? Or scoped (request life time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure I understand what your code is supposed to do (your registrations).

It's a bit odd, as you register a singleton in the first line and you seem to resolve it similar to a transient in your second line, but since it's registered as singleton, it would always return the same. So what's the second line supposed to do?

Are you looking for a factory method?

```
public static void Register(IServiceCollection services) 
{
    services.AddSingleton<IEventStoreUnitOfWork<IDomainEvent>,EventStoreUnitOfWork<IDomainEvent>>();
     // AddScoped = request-lifetime, AddTransint = instantiate on each resolve
     services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork>( provider => provider.RequestService<IEventStoreUnitOfWork<IDomainEvent>>();
}
```

The second overload of the `AddXxx` methods allows you to use a delegate to provide a factory method. The parameter passed to the delegate will be `IServiceProvider` (which is the container after it's been built from `IServiceCollection`), so you can call `RequestService` (is the ASP.NET Cores `Resolve` method) inside it and return the resolved type.

Comment: Thank you! I know my code looks a little bit odd but as I mentioned this is a legacy project and I need to move it to ASP.NET Core in short terms. Your solution is exactly what I've been looking for!

Comment: Right, but isn't the second line obsolete in the first place? I mean, when you resolve `IUnitOfWork` you get the **same** instance as resolving `IEventStoreUnitOfWork<IDomainEvent>`, so a `services.AddSingleton<IUnitOfWork,EventStoreUnitOfWork<IDomainEvent>>();` should result in the same, right?

Comment: indeed, but for some reason some services in the project use IUnitOfWork interface and some IEventStoreUnitOfWork<IDomainEvemt>. yet they all relies on the same instance.. and I hesitate to make any changes for now.